# White Spots on Wood in Attic

Tags: wood, ceiling, attic, mold, moisture

Went up to the attic today and saw these white spots on the wood for the ceiling. Just wondering what they are and if I should be concerned? And also how to get rid of it and prevent it from coming back?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's mold.  Likely not serious enough to worry about, but I'm sure someone sells a spray that would kill the stuff and keep it from returning.

Comment: Usually something like bleach will kill it, but there are mold removers/killers/cleaners sold.  More ventilation will help to keep it from coming back.